# Value not changing in for loop

Tags: java

I am currently working on a program to show a phrase in font sizes from 6-20. In the loop to create these phrases the loop does not change the y value/s of the different phrases. They seem to be created on top of eachother. Here is the code.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class JFontSizesPanel extends JPanel
{
 String phrase = new String("This is a phrase in every font size from 6 to 20");
 int start = 6;
 int y;

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
 {
  super.paintComponent(gr);
  for (int i = 6; i < 20; i++)  
  {
   Font myFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, start);
   y = 30;
   y = y + 30;
   start = start + 1;
   gr.setFont(myFont);
   gr.drawString(phrase, 0, y);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   JFontSizesPanel fonts = new JFontSizesPanel();
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFontSizesPanel");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.add(fonts);
   frame.setSize(1000,1000);
   frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

My first time posting so sorry for poor formatting and any help is appreciated.

Comment: `y = 30;` - this should be before the loop.

Comment: And y should be declared inside paintComponent(), not as a field. Same for start.

Answer (score 2):

declare y = 30 before for loop.

```
y = 30;
for (int i = 6; i < 20; i++)  
{
   Font myFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, start);
   y = y + 30;
   start = start + 1;
   gr.setFont(myFont);
   gr.drawString(phrase, 0, y);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int y = 30;
```

you have to declare the first value outside of your loop. otherwise it will be resetted in every iteration.